# ColdFusion 10 not writing to cfcookie on same browser but different computers

Tags: coldfusion

I am migrating websites from a server using CF 8 to a new one using CF 10. In this one site, I have a query that looks up talent and then writes the resulting list to a cfcookie. On my computer with any browser it works correctly. My client uses the same browser as I normally use (Safari) and his browser is not updating the cfcookie with the new talent list after a search. They are very unhappy making me unhappy also. Any ideas as to what might be causing this problem.

In the application.cfm (yes, I know I should be updating to cfc but not enough hours in the day):

```
<CFAPPLICATION NAME="lil" 
CLIENTMANAGEMENT="yes"
SESSIONMANAGEMENT="yes"
SESSIONTIMEOUT=" #createTimeSpan(0,0,30,0)#"
APPLICATIONTIMEOUT=" #createTimeSpan(0,1,0,0)#"
clientstorage="cookie">
```

Setting the cfcookie:

```
<cfif isdefined('getTalent.recordcount') and getTalent.recordcount gt 0>
    <cfcookie name="tSearch" value="#valueList(getTalent.talentID)#" httponly="true" expires="1">
 </cfif>
```

Comment: Are cookies enabled on client browser ? http://www.timeanddate.com/custom/cookiesother.html

Comment: Yes. Testing more showed that once a cookie has been set, it will not allow me to change the value.

Answer (score 0):

How large is the amount of data you are storing in the cookie, and could the client be storing more than you are?  Are they possibly using a cookie-blocking security app of some kind?

In a bigger-picture kind of mindset, if the user is doing a search and getting results, rather than storing the results in a cookie, why not use either a session-scoped variable, or simply use the CF identity cookies already in place to store their results in a temporary database location?  Cookie issues can be harder to track down, but unless you're not managing sessions in your Application.cfc or cfapplication tag, each user is already getting a unique ID which you can leverage server-side for this type of thing.

One last thought... are you doing any sort of CFLOCATION redirect, after attempting to store the cookie?  Redirecting can cause CFCOOKIE commands to not be honored, because in essence the user's browser is redirected before it receives the response.